# Convert dictionaries inside into list in nested dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary like this

```
{'C': 
    {
    'G': 
        {
            'Z': '4', 'L': '1', 'P': [{'K': '3', 'B': '1'}, {'K': '7', 'B': '9'}]
        }   
    }
}
```

and I'm trying to convert to list each `value` that is a `dictionary` in order to get a new  dictionary like this

```
{'C': 
    [{
    'G': 
        [{
            'Z': '4', 'L': '1', 'P': [{'K': '3', 'B': '1'}, {'K': '7', 'B': '9'}]
        }]  
    }]
}
```

To see it easely would be pass from dict1 to dict2

[image]

My attempt so far is like this. Thanks in advance.

```
>>> for k, v in d1.items():
...     if isinstance(v, dict):
...         d1[k,v] = d1[k,[v]]
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Comment: What if using a new dictionary instead of reusing d1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use recursion:

```
def to_list(d):
   if not isinstance(d, (dict, list)):
      return d
   if isinstance(d, list):
      return list(map(to_list, d))
   return {a:to_list(b) if not isinstance(b, dict) else [to_list(b)] for a, b in d.items()}

vals = {'C': {'G': {'Z': '4', 'L': '1', 'P': [{'K': '3', 'B': '1'}, {'K': '7', 'B': '9'}]}}}
r = to_list(vals)
```

Output:

```
{'C': [{'G': [{'Z': '4', 'L': '1', 'P': [{'K': '3', 'B': '1'}, {'K': '7', 'B': '9'}]}]}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want your key to be `k` then you don't want `d1[k,v]`, rather you should set `d1[k] = [v]`

Note that you have not provided a way to go deeper into the dictionary, this will only convert top-level values that are dicts to lists containing the dict. You'll need a way to recurse into those dicts if you wish to convert any dicts that they contain as values.

Answer (score 1):

You can try recursion:

```py
dct = {
    "C": {
        "G": {
            "Z": "4",
            "L": "1",
            "P": [{"K": "3", "B": "1"}, {"K": "7", "B": "9"}],
        }
    }
}


def convert(d):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        out = {}
        for k, v in d.items():
            out[k] = [convert(v)] if isinstance(v, dict) else convert(v)
        return out
    elif isinstance(d, list):
        return [convert(v) for v in d]
    return d


print(convert(dct))
```

Prints:

```py
{
    "C": [
        {
            "G": [
                {
                    "Z": "4",
                    "L": "1",
                    "P": [{"K": "3", "B": "1"}, {"K": "7", "B": "9"}],
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Recursive approach

```
d = {'C':
    {
    'G':
        {
            'Z': '4', 'L': '1', 'P': [{'K': '3', 'B': '1'}, {'K': '7', 'B': '9'}]
        }
    }
}

def d2l(d):
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            d2l(v)
            d[k] = [v]

    return d

new_dict = d2l(d)
print(new_dict)
```

Output

```
{'C': [{'G': [{'Z': '4', 'L': '1', 'P': [{'K': '3', 'B': '1'}, {'K': '7', 'B': '9'}]}]}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use recursion, this seemed to work for me:

```
main = {
    'C': {
        'G': {
            'Z': '4',
            'L': '1',
            'P': [{'K': '3', 'B': '1'},
                  {'K': '7', 'B': '9'}]
            }
        }
}


def convert_dictionary(dictionary: dict):
    for key, value in dictionary.items():
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            convert_dictionary(value)
            dictionary[key] = [value]


convert_dictionary(main)
print(main)
```

Tell me if it helped!

Comment: Thanks for your help. It seems doesn't make change with more levels.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another recursion solution (added a third level)

```
def toList(d, d2):
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            d2[k] = [v]
            toList(v, d2[k][0])

d1 = {'C':
    {
    'G':
        {
            'Z': '4', 'L': '1', 'P': [{'K': '3', 'B': '1'}],
             "thirdLvl": {'K': '7', 'B': '9'}
        }
    }
}


d2 = {}

toList(d1,d2)
print(d2)
```

Result:

```
{'C': 
     [{'G': 
           [{'Z': '4', 'L': '1', 'P': [{'K': '3', 'B': '1'}],
             'thirdLvl': [{'K': '7', 'B': '9'}]
            }
           ]
      }
     ]
}
```